# Protect workbook but allow changes by code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I'm looking for the equivalent of the following statement, but for workbook protection:

```
Worksheet.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly := True
```

So I don't want the user to tamper with the workbook, but changes by code are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible as Workbook.Protect() method has no such parameter.
Rather you can try to *unprotect the workbook*... *do your code*... *protect the workbook again.*

```
Public Sub UserProtection()
    Const PASS As String = "666bytes" 
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect (PASS)
    '...YOUR CODE...what you want to do...
    ThisWorkbook.Protect (PASS)
End Sub
```

Also, let me remind you that keeping the password in plain string format (like in this example) is not a good practice. (not that it will help very much if someone wants to crack your sheet) ... :) just FYI

Comment: In order to prevent the clear text password from being read, it's best practice to also protect the VBA project with a password.